# Postgres - super slow query - wierd behaviour

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-12

Im struggling with super slow query which contains hundreds of AND .. OR conditions / text parameters - no joins etc (this is part of closed system co query cannot be easily changed)

Query slowed down recently, after some maintenance we did on DB (before it was executed few seconds, now ~30 mins)
I tried to analyse it - it does basically Bitmap Heap Scan than hundreds  Bitmap Index Scan's for each AND condition

As this is closed (vendor) system I cant do much, but I wonder why it slowed down so much from day to day...

I tried:

- Reindex Table - still slow
- Full Vacuum Table - slow
- vacuum full Database - slow
- Restore DB from SQL Dump - slow
- Copy data to table B - FAST AGAIN!
- Truncate data and copy back from table A - FAST!

Query plan was exactly the same in all cases..

Can someone explain me what is happening here?

Table size: ~6'000'000 rows
PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: Could you share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, COSTS) for this query? And also when the query is fast (again). There must be a difference. And is there some other proces running on this (virtual?) machine as well?

Comment: Did you try just vacuuming the table?  VACUUM FULL does more than a regular VACUUM, but it also does less.  Do you have long-running transactions?

Comment: This a question with a lot of text but not much information. In addition to the a fore mentioned `EXPLAIN` add to you question:  1) What '... after some maintenance we did .. ' means? 2) The table definition. 3) What are tables A and B?

Comment: During the Maintenance we have deleted older records in some tables (not related to this one) + DB Vacuum / Analyses was executed. All those checks were done in isolated mode (single user, no other queries run i background)

Comment: Also Im sorry as this is vendor system I affraid I cannot share table structure / query plans without hashing.
My question was more general - why making copy of data, truncating original table and copy if back resulting better performance. Or mabe this causes data is better organized now?

Comment: In both cases I can see exactly the same query plan:
1. Bitmap Heap Scan on ... (lot of ANDs and ORs) 2.   ->  BitmapOr (...) 3. and hundreds ->  Bitmap Index Scan on (..) Index cond: (...) AND (...)
Only difference FAST vs SLOW is order of those Bitmap Index Scans conditions

Comment: What did your vendor tell you to do when you told them about the issue?

Comment: They said they know this is not optimal, and plan to change that in future, but if this worked acceptable before they said this must be something with our DB / Server..

Comment: If they take substantially different amounts of time, they must have substantially different `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`, as the timings are part of that--even if the overall plan shape is the same.  And that goes doubly for `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` if track_io_timing is turned on.  https://explain.depesz.com/ provides a way to obfuscate plans by renaming the tables columns, and constants. Maybe you could use that to share the plans with us.

Comment: Check logging configuration, maybe you have active full logging on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you all commenting. Please note my question was not about how to review / optimize query plan (this should be vendor task) but rather - why if I copy data to new table query works faster there, same when I truncate oryginal table and copy data back from temp table - but still slow when I a) vacuum (full) old table, b) reindex  old table c) restore entire DB from SQL dump. Same server config, no changes, no other queries